# How do I import a csv file with shiny

Tags: r

I want to import data into a shiny app. I simply have a csv file with a date column and two columns of numeric values that will end up being charted. Basically I want to import this interactive.csv file (which is kept in a data folder within the app folder) which will be read into a data frame called Surveillance.

```
source ("claman-app/data/interactive.csv"
Surveillance <- read.csv(claman-app/data/interactive.csv)
Surveillance <- data.frame( 
    Date = seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2015/12/31"), "days"),
    zoom = as.numeric(sample(1:100,365,replace=T)), chat                 =as.numeric(sample(1:100,365,replace=T)))

Surveillance <- Surveillance %>% mutate(
    Week = format(Date, "%Y-%m-%U")),
```

Comment: `source()` is for R files, not CSV files. Try `Surveillance <- read.csv("claman-app/data/interactive.csv")` (with quotes). You need to pass the path as a character/string value. The path should be relative to your `app.R` file that you are using to run the shiny app. So you might just need `Surveillance <- read.csv("data/interactive.csv")`

Comment: That doesn't work. I get no errors but R just ignores that the file is there.  I have the app file in a folder called claman with the .csv file in the data directory within that folder.  I've tried calling it referring to a folder on the desktop. Same thing, It's like the data in interactive.csv is invisible. The app executes perfectly -- just without the data.  I put it all in a github repository.  https://github.com/karl1776/interactive  Thanks.

Comment: Well what do you do with the `Surveillance` object after you import the data? What does your actual app look like. Where exactly is the code chunk you are showing?

Comment: Seems to work fine when I run the code. I did have to change `read.csv("/data/interactive.csv", as.is=T)`. There should not be a "/" in front of data, but that should have given you an error.

Comment: I posted all of this at github https://github.com/karl1776/interactive  I think I am somehow passing the date from the csv file incorrectly.